# Restart a tictactoe game after a win

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my `checkWin()` below I'm trying to give an option of quitting or restarting when the game has been won. With what I have currently it will allow me to 'restart' but it's actually just letting me continue to play with the current board. In other words, I can't figure out a way to start fresh. What's more is that I don't think what I've done in `checkWin()` is very clean. Looking for pointers on what to do.

(I'm aware there are other kinks in this script, but I'm working one thing at a time)

```
'''Tic-tac-toe game'''

import sys
import time
import random


def printBoard():
    print "\n"
    print "  1 |  2 |  3 "
    print "____|____|____"
    print "  4 |  5 |  6 "
    print "____|____|____"
    print "  7 |  8 |  9 "
    print "    |    |    "
    print "\n"

def makeMove():
    move = raw_input("\nIt's your turn. Choose a box between 1 and 9: \n")
    move = int(move)
    return move

def boardCurrent(takenSpots):
    print "",takenSpots[0]," |",takenSpots[1]," |",takenSpots[2],"  "
    print "____|____|____"
    print "",takenSpots[3]," |",takenSpots[4]," |",takenSpots[5],"  "
    print "____|____|____"
    print "",takenSpots[6]," |",takenSpots[7]," |",takenSpots[8],"  "
    print "    |    |    "
    print "\n"

def compMove(takenSpots):
    move = random.randint(0,8)
    if takenSpots[move] == " ":
        takenSpots[move] = "O"
    else:
        compMove(takenSpots)
    return takenSpots

def takeSpot(move):
    if takenSpots[move - 1] != " ":
        print "That spot is taken, choose another."
        takeSpot(makeMove())
    else:
        takenSpots[move - 1] = "X"
    return takenSpots

def checkWin(takenSpots):
    win_positions = [
    (0, 3, 6),
    (1, 4, 7),
    (2, 5, 8),
    (0, 1, 2),
    (3, 4, 5),
    (6, 7, 8),
    (0, 4, 8),
    (2, 4, 6),
    ]
    for line in win_positions:
        if all(takenSpots[position] == "X" for position in line):
            win = True
            print "You win."
            if win == True:
                endgame = int(raw_input("Would you like to play another round?\n1) Yes\n2) No, this sucks. I want to quit."))
            if endgame == 1:
                main()
            if endgame == 2:
                sys.exit()
            return win
        if all(takenSpots[position] == "O" for position in line):
            win = True
            print "The computer won."
            return win

def clearBoard():
    takenSpots = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
    return takenSpots

def main():
    boardCurrent(takeSpot(makeMove()))
    checkWin(takenSpots)
    print "Now the computer will go...\n"
    time.sleep(1)
    compMove(takenSpots)
    boardCurrent(takenSpots)
    checkWin(takenSpots)

takenSpots = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]

print "\nWelcome to tic-tac-toe."
win = False
printBoard()
main() 
while win == False:
    main()
```

Comment: In `checkWin()` you create a *local* variable `win`. I'm sure you mean to set a *global* variable. You need to use the `global` keyword at the beginning of the function to tell the interpreter that you are using the global variable.

Comment: I would consider making the game object-oriented with a `Board` class and some sort of `Controller` class (or just a `main()` function). The 'Board' class should have methods for displaying itself, resetting itself, making moves, and returning the state or status of each board position. Your `checkwin()` function can then use those methods to deterimine its result and return it to `main()` or one of the `Controller`'s methods which can decide whether to continue playing or declare the winner and reset the `Board` instance (or create a new one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without showing you exactly how to do it, as you are capable of that I imagine, I would suggest you nest the whole program in a while loop like this:

```
while True:
    program...
```

And when a game is won or tied, ask the user for input, like whether to quit or restart:

```
Enter q to quit or r to restart # for instance
```

if q is entered, simply break from the while loop with the break statement, and end the program, or else, for a restart, loop back, redrawing the board and well, basically just reset any variable where necessary. With some thought for the loop it is not too difficult.

checkwin:

I would re-evaluate the usefulness/necessity of the variable 'win'. Is it really needed? If so, is it being used properly? Maybe if you implement the while loop solution this issue will become more apparent. I see you have a loop, `while win == False`, but I'm not sure that win always gets evaluated properly for the situation where the player wins.